# ssh from a cluster node triggers public key error for all remote hosts (MWE for github)

Tags: github, ssh, public-key-encryption

#### Question:

For some reason all remote hosts stopped accepting my ssh key.
While troubleshooting this, I finally realized that even removing my public key completely from github (which should still fall back to password until 8/13) still produces a "publickey" error.  How do I fix this?

#### Steps to reproduce:

1. remove my cluster account public key from github user settings
2. attempt to connect (produces error)

```
[me@login-node:/data/homevols/me] $ssh -T git@github.com
Permission denied (publickey).
```

#### Sanity-check:

```
[me@login-node:/data/homevols/me] $less ~/.ssh/config
Host *
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
/data/homevols/me/.ssh/config (END)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen GitHub fall back to password with SSH: it uses the technical account `git`, for which there is no password anyway.
That means `ssh -oPubkeyAuthentication=no git@github.com` would still return `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).`, without asking for password.

In your case: generate a new SSH key, add the public one to your profile, and try again:

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

You should see a [Welcome message](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection)

```sh
> Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
> provide shell access.
```